# Use pandas to replace whitespace (" ,") with empty string (",") in csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, etl

I have a large csv that has null values as whitespace (e.g. " ,").  I need to turn them all to empty strings (",") for some datatype-specific stuff I need to do in postgres.

I thought this would be a FAQ, but I can't seem to find another example of someone doing this in Pandas.

I'm guessing I need to iterate through my csv and replace each instance of ", ," with ",,".

Here's an example of two rows.  You can see that the empty cells are whitespaces:

```
11111.00130.00000,12,NAME NAME T YES,2017,0,1477.51,1477.51, ,444 ALPHABET AVE,COLUMBUS,AL,12345-4544,RESIDENTIAL,10/1/2017, ,N,Y,ROBERTS,BLOCK 1,LOTS 19-20, , , ,1/1/1900, , ,479.29,159.95,327.14,104.27,406.86,0,0,0,0
11111.00130.00000,12,NAME NAME T YES,2016,0,1411.59,1411.59, ,333 ALPHABET AVE,COLUMBUS,AL,12345-4544,RESIDENTIAL,10/1/2016, ,N,Y,ROBERTS,BLOCK 1,LOTS 19-20, , , ,1/1/1900, , ,479.29,158.58,312.6,72.95,388.17,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: This is pretty prominent in the pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html -- `df.fillna("")`

Comment: You don't say anything about how your are importing the csv or what datatypes you are working with. You may want look at `pandas.DataFrame.replace` though. However, if you aren't using pandas to work with the data, pandas might not be your best option to do this.

Comment: Please show your data and a [mcve]

Comment: Just added two example rows -- thanks for the comments!

Comment: `df.replace(' ', '')` ?

Comment: Inside of a for loop like this?
import csv
import pandas

f = pd.read_csv('Copy.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for item in csv_f:
 df.replace(' ','')

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('Copy.csv;)` then just `df.replace(' ', '')`

Comment: So the full script would just be this? It doesn't seem to have done anything? import csv
import pandas

df = pd.read_csv('Copy.csv')

df.replace(' ','')

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a fillna function.
 `df.fillna("")`

Does this not solve what you want?

Comment: Would I do something like this?

import csv

f = open('file.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for item in csv_f:
 for field in item:
  field.replace(', ,', ',,')

Comment: This issue is that the empty cells have a space in them.

Comment: Can you try reading the csv and performing df.replace(' ', '') ? If you include a sample of your data frame in question, it would be really helpful exactly understand what you mean

Comment: I just added two example rows

Comment: I tried to read the data you have included, and tried to replace the empty column data with a text called 'test' and it works well. dff=pd.read_csv('test098.csv',header=-1) ; df5=dff.replace(' ','test') ; df5[14]

Comment: and the empty quotes in dff.replace(' ','test') is a space!

Answer (score 0):

Basically to say, @RafaelC's comment can help you, just add some attention for you to form a complete code, FYI.

```
csv = pd.read_csv('old.csv', header=-1)
# print(len(csv[7][0])) # if uncomment the output: 1
csv.replace(' ', '', inplace=True)
# print(len(csv[7][0])) # if uncomment the output: 0
csv.to_csv('new.csv', header=0)
```

Here, when read csv, need to let pandas auto generate column name for you(`header=-1`), otherwise, the first line data will be set as column name. Then, the replace will not effect on the first line.

When write csv(if you needed), need to ignore the column name(`header=0`), so the auto generated column name will not be written to new csv, you can check the new csv to see the effect.